# How to supply $HOME or $COMPOSER_HOME option via salt state.apply?

Tags: php, composer-php, devops, salt-stack

I'm trying to install composer via salt. Here is the composer.sls I am using:

```
get-composer:
 cmd.run:
    - name: 'CURL=`which curl`; $CURL -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php'
    - unless: test -f /usr/local/bin/composer
    - cwd: /root/

install-composer:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: mv /root/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    - cwd: /root/
    - watch:
      - cmd: get-composer
```

I am running it like this:

```
salt 'webserver' state.apply composer
```

The error that I am getting says (in part):

```
stdout:
              All settings correct for using Composer
              The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
Summary for webserver
------------
Succeeded: 0 (changed=1)
Failed:    2
```

Now here's what I am having trouble groking.

On the [Composer Salt formula documentation page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.composer.html#salt.states.composer.installed), it says:

```
Installed ... composer_home=u'/root'
```

and `$COMPOSER_HOME` is one of the options. How do I supply this option? I'm just not finding it on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by defining COMPOSER_HOME under env variable like below:

```
get-composer:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'CURL=`which curl`; $CURL -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php'
    - unless: test -f /usr/local/bin/composer
    - cwd: /var/www/
    - env:
      - COMPOSER_HOME : /var/www

install-composer:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: mv /var/www/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    - cwd: /var/www/
    - watch:
      - cmd: get-composer
```